# Javascript numbers - whole number with two decimals but keep as number

Tags: javascript, numbers

I have a requirement to format numbers on the ui as numbers but with two decimal places.  I have used toFixed(2) but it converts it to a string. Is there a way to keep a whole number with two decimals but store it as a number? Example: 75.00 as a number not a string.

Comment: keep 75 in your variables/model/whatever and only convert it to string when showing it on the page, at the latest time possible.

Comment: No problem, keep the whole number in memory but render to view via `toFixed(2)`

Comment: The requirement is to store it in memory as 75.00. Is this possible?

Comment: Not as a number.  `75` is the numerical representation.  If you want it to have decimals in memory, format it as a string.